# Network Error MAAS

Tags: networking, maas, openstack

I can not get MAAS to deploy a node. I can power the node off and on. I get the error below.

Error:Node failed to be deployed, because of the following error: {"network": ["Node has no address family in common with the server"]}

I think is has to do with the reserved range on the subnet. My MAAS server has a static address of 192.168.200.180/24. The reserved range on the subnet in MAAS that automatically configures is 192.168.200.190/24 - 192.168.200.252/24. The server still lives in the same address space of 192.168.200.0/24. I can not adjust the range to 192.168.200.1/24. I get the error below.

Error: Requested dynamic range conflicts with an existing IP address or range.

I would really like to get this working so I can deploy a Ubuntu OpenStack private cloud.

MAAS version: 2.4.0~beta2 (6865-gec43e47e6-0ubuntu1)

Thanks,

Jason R Gann

Comment: Ok I figured this out. I deleted the reserved range 192.168.200.190/24 - 192.168.200.252/24 that was automatically assigned by MAAS. I don't really need it anyway. I then had to go into the Machines tab for the node I was having problems deploying. Then I clicked on the Interfaces tab. Then edit the interface that was connected by clicking the three lines under the actions tab at the end of the interface tabs and choose edit interface. Make sure the Subnet is assigned to the subnet you are deploying on. Make sure the IP mode is set to auto assign.

Comment: After doing all that I was able to deploy the node. Hopefully no one wasted any time working on this...

Comment: Hi Jason.  I just wanted to thank you for coming back and posting the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I switched the subnet for the MAAS PXE boot network connection for the new node from IPv4 to IPv6 and now it starts the deploy. Apparently MAAS has forgotten that is has both IPv4 and IPv6 enabled on the PXE boot network. What is odd, is the first two systems I deployed used IPv4 addresses.

But the deploy is failing .. but that's a different issue.